# R: Classify numeric vector in factor groups

Tags: r

I have a numeric variable age:

```
age <- ceiling(runif(1000, 1, 99))
```

I want to create a factor variable with levels distinguishing

- 25 years or under
- 26 to 35 years
- 36 to 45 years
- 46 to 55 years
- 56 to 65 years
- 66 to 75 years
- 76 years or over.

I've tried to use the cut function

```
age <-cut(age, breaks = seq(26, 77, by = 9))
```

but I don't get the desired result. 
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You need to set endpoints outside your range, e.g. `cut(age, c(0, seq(25, 77, by = 9), Inf))`

Comment: Actually,  more is wrong than the endpoints.  I think that you need `cut(age,breaks = c(0, seq(25,75,by=10), 100))`

Comment: Thank your for your answer actually I should get age groups from 26 to 35 - 36 to 45, whereas I am getting: "(0,25]"   "(25,35]"  "(35,45]"  "(45,55]"  "(55,65]"  "(65,75]"  "(75,100]" . Maybe I should not use seq()?

Comment: **You are getting what you ask for** with G5W's comment. (At least as specifically as you ask for it - you don't mention what to do with decimals between your breaks: where does 25.5 go? It's neither in 0-25 nor 26-35.) `(` denotes an "open" end of an interval (not including the endpoint) and `]` denotes a "closed" end of an interval, including an endpoint. If you have decimal ages and want 25.9999 included in the 0-25 age group, then add 1 to your breaks and set `right = FALSE`. Also feel free to specify custom `labels`. See `?cut` for details.